# Freezing algorithm in a blockchain network

Tags: mining, algorithm

Is there any algorithm or mechanism in any blockchain network to automatically freeze a miner for a certain period of time upon certain conditions? So that the freezed miner can no longer participate in the mining process for the time being and will be automatically unfrozen after certain conditions have been met. If so kindly provide me with the algorithm or mechanism that is being implemented in a blockchain network.